# Bootstrap modal losing data when displayed

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that has various buttons on that when clicked display a modal popup. The popup displays correctly on the screen, but no data appears in any of the fields.

When I step through the code I can see that the data is being assigned to the relevant controls (textbox or label) but nothing appears. In my project I have several other forms that also have popups and these work as they should. I have even used the code from these forms to try and solve the issue but with no success.

This is the code where the user clicks the button to display the popup

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabDiary">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelDiary" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <%--<asp:Timer ID="timerDiary" runat="server" Interval="15000" OnTick="timerDiary_Tick"></asp:Timer>--%>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptDiary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptDiary_ItemDataBound">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDiary" runat="server" Text="New Diary Item" OnClick="btnDiary_Click" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Visible="true" />
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="tabHeaderRow">
                                    <td>Date</td>
                                    <td>Entered By</td>
                                    <td>Comments</td>
                                    <td>Action Date</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DateEntered") %></td>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AddedBy") %></td>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Comments") %></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblActionDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ActionDate") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Button ID="btnEditDiaryEntry" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditDiaryEntry"
                                 OnCommand="btnEditDiaryEntry_Command" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DiaryID") %>' /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

This is the code behind:

```
    protected void btnEditDiaryEntry_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 DiaryID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetDiaryEntry", cnn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiaryID", DiaryID);
        cnn.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            txtEditComment.Text = dr["Comments"].ToString();
            txtEditScheduleDiary.Text = dr["ActionDate"].ToString();
        }

        dr.Close();
        cnn.Close();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(_parentControl, _parentControl.GetType(), "Modal", " DisplayEditDiaryModal()", true);
        Master.GetMenuData();
        txtEditScheduleDiary.Text = "hello david";

    }
```

And this is the code to display the popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayEditDiaryModal() {
        $('#<%=pnlDiaryEdit.ClientID%>').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

This is the code for the modal:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDiaryEdit" runat="server" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="well well-md">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-center header"><asp:Label ID="Label31" Text="Edit Diary Entry" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label></legend>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidDiaryID" runat="server" />

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditComment" runat="server" Text="Comment"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditComment" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Wrap="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditSchedule" runat="server" Text="Schedule Event"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditScheduleDiary" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelEdit" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="HideEditDiaryModal(); return false;" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEditDiary" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnEditDiary_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </div>                       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I have already said this code works on other forms within the project. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding updatePanelDiary.Update()?

```
protected void btnEditDiaryEntry_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 DiaryID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetDiaryEntry", cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiaryID", DiaryID);
    cnn.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        txtEditComment.Text = dr["Comments"].ToString();
        txtEditScheduleDiary.Text = dr["ActionDate"].ToString();
    }

    dr.Close();
    cnn.Close();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(_parentControl, _parentControl.GetType(), "Modal", " DisplayEditDiaryModal()", true);
    Master.GetMenuData();
    txtEditScheduleDiary.Text = "hello david";

    updatePanelDiary.Update();
}
```

And add UpdateMode="Conditional" to your update panel

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelDiary" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid it still didnt work. The text boxes are still blank

Comment: It seems like you forgot to add the html of your modal. Possible to edit your question and add it?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I have amended my question to show the code

Comment: Have you tried using the good ID's? You seem to be changing txtEditComment in your C# but in your modal I only see txtComment

Comment: Sorry copied the wrong piece of code, have amended the question

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to insert your panel inside an UpdatePanel and Update it in btnEditDiaryEntry_Command()

Comment: I am about to finish for the day. I will try your suggestion in the morning and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your assistance today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185422/discussion-between-david-cleeton-and-cheon).